# PreferenceFragment no scroll in CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, preferencefragment

I have a problem with PreferenceFragment and CollapsingToolbarLayout. I have a base layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.base.BaseActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/ctlLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabFav"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="85dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbarLayout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabShare"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbarLayout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/search_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.eventum.raedictionary.fragments.SearchFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search"/>
```

The problem is when I inflate the Framelayout with a PreferenceFragment the scroll doesn't work but with a normal Fragment works properly.

```
        BaseSettingFragment settingsFragment = new BaseSettingFragment();

        fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.transition.fade_in, R.transition.fade_out);

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, settingsFragment);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I haven't found any solutions for this problem, can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance.

PD: Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`PreferenceFragment` is based on `ListView`, which does not support the nested scrolling APIs required for `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. You can instead use the [Preference Support Library](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/9kZ3SsXdT2T) and [PreferenceFragmentCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html), which is based on `RecyclerView` and *does* support the nested scrolling APIs required.